# How can I make autosized tables cells be wide enough so that italic text does not overflow

Tags: html, css, html-table

The following Html shows how italic content of a table cell overflow, in Firefox, Chrome, and IE8 in standards mode. (In IE quirks mode extra padding is appended to the right of the table cell so the text doesn't overflow)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
TD {
    BORDER: #000000 1px solid;
}
TD.Italic {
    FONT-STYLE: italic; Font-Size: 200%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" >
<tr>
<td class="Italic">
fff
</td>
</tr>
</html>
```

[image: screen shot of rendered HTML]

What is the best way to make autosized tables cells be wide enough so that italic text does not overflow?

I know I can extend the cell by a fixed amount doing somthing like this: `padding-right: 10px;` but for this I have to ensure this  padding 'fudge value' is big enough to accommodate large font sizes which creates an unnecessary amount of white space for smaller font sizes.

I don't want to clip the text or add a scrollbar, I want the cell to be wide enough to display all the italic text.

Comment: Is something wrong with setting the padding using em?

Comment: You mean something like this: padding-right: 0.2em; padding-left: 0.2em; This seems much better than fixed pixel padding... thanks